# exporting 3dsmax file with animations to threejs

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, 3dsmax

I'm new to `3dsmax and threejs`.  I bought a rigged model with several animations in the same file, but I'm having trouble understanding how to export into threejs.  I tried using the instructions here: http://blog.andrewray.me/how-to-export-a-rigged-animated-model-from-3ds-max-three-js/

but it seems as though this plugin **`ThreeJSAnimationExporter.ms`** is expecting a mesh.  From what I can tell, the model I purchased is a combo of biped objects or something.

All I want to do is export the animations(preferably 1 by 1) and mess with them in threejs.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: update: I did get past the problem above by adding a 'Edit Mesh' modifier...whatever that means.  But now I'm getting this: runtime skin need to be selected and in the modifier panel skin

Comment: You are diving in pretty deep if you don't know 3ds max or three.js. The tutorial mentions that it needs to be rigged with bones, not biped. If the model is already rigged, I don't think you want to put an edit mesh modifier on. Without seeing the state of your model/max file it is going to be hard to help you.

Comment: You can convert a biped rig to 'bones' by exporting it out to FBX format and import it back in again, this will create the biped as regular bone objects.

Also - the error you mention is because you need to select the 'skin' modifier in the stack (it seems), and since you added edit mesh on top then it does not seem to find the skin modifier (bad coding in the script if you ask me).

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I do feel as though I'm a bit in over my head, but mostly from the 3dsmax side of things.  I am a web dev and have a lot of experience in javascript, but I can't even get my animations exported yet, heh.  I'm trying to mess with openCollada now to see if that is a better path.  I've watched some tutorials on 3dsmax via digital-tutors but they don't really talk about exporting your model/animations.  THanks again.